# Are there any references to "Sakkarai Palam" in Ayurveda?

Tags: tamil, ayurveda

What is "Sakkarai palam" (called in English)? (Anyone from Tamil Nadu must have heard about it).

Are there any references to the fruit in ayurveda?

Comment: it is jamaican it has many health benefits

Comment: Muntingia calabura. This is the scientific name of sakkarai pazham

Answer (score 1):

Sakkarai Palam

Binomial Name : Grewia hirsute

Family        : [Tiliaceae]

[image: Tiliaceae]

May Be something like this,

[I Found Here](http://www.avpayurveda.com/dmdocuments/OND05.7.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muntingia

Muntingia calabura[image]

Muntingia calabura is a shrub or tree up to 12 m tall with spreading branches. The leaves are alternate, distichous, oblong or lanceolate, 4–15 cm long and 1–6 cm wide, with toothed margin and covered in short hairs. The flowers are small (up to 3cm wide), solitary or in inflorescences of 2-3 flowers; with 5 lanceolate sepals, hairy; 5 obovate white petals; many stamens with yellow anthers and a smooth ovoid ovary.Fruit, an edible berry, red at maturity, about 1.5 cm wide.

Comment: Welcome , although you tried to adress the issue in the question , the enquiry in the question is related to Ayurveda.Pls.edit your answer as per the requirement's of the question.